# advantages/disadvantages to using webview as an application

Tags: android, webview

I am building a mobile application that takes information received from a server and displays it to the user. This is done in Android Studio (it would be released for android and ios).

The mvp application simply has the information in a webpage, which is displayed via fullscreen webview:

(data input --> server--> webpage-->application-(webpage via webview)->user

As an mvp iteration, ***what are the advantages/disadvantages*** to:

- using the webview to display the webpage (assuming that javascript is enabled)

  (data input --> server--> webpage-->application-(webpage via webview)->user
- taking information directly from the server and use the appropriate widgets to create the UI

  (data input --> server--> application -->user)

Thanks all.

Comment: Check [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) et al for easy android and ios development (code once, build many)

Comment: Okay thanks, unfortunately I can't be too specific as it's the code for a startup. The networking dev suggested that we just keep everything in a webview, but I wasnt sure how this would work out.

Comment: The biggest problem with WebView I see is it's aggressive security policy regarding the page [origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812066/html5-localstorage-not-working-on-android-webview)(Both Android and iOS use WebvView in Cordova for cross platform support)

Comment: This kind of open-ended question is probably best suited to  [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/) site .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me sum up some pros and cons real quick:

**Pro(s)**

- Your UI can be easily ported to other platforms

**Cons**

- `WebViews` are heavyweight containers
- User Interaction is not implemented as straightforward as you would do it in plain Android Java

Last but not least, the question that everybody will be asking you if you do it like that: Why not simply provide your service through a webpage (browser)?